# What is 0 dB in Periodogram?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

Consider some sound:

```
ViolinNote = Sound[SoundNote["G", 1, "Violin"]]
```

We may plot the periodogram:

```
Periodogram[ViolinNote]
```

[image]

The y-axis is the amplitude in dB, while the x-axis is the frequency in Hz. My question is about the meaning of 0 dB: does it mean that everything below 0 dB is not audible, and if yes then how does Mathematica extract it?

I.e., the definition the amplitude in dB, according to the [reference](https://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/dB.htm), is

$$
\text{Amplitude (dB)} = 10\log\left( \frac{P_{2}}{P_{1}}\right)
$$
where $P_{2}$ is the power (just the Fourier coefficient squared) of the given tone $\omega_{2}$. What Mathematica uses for $P_{1}$, i.e., how does Mathematica define it? I have not found the corresponding information in the documentation.

Clearly, 0 dB is not the audibility limit: one may apply the highpass filter

```
ViolinNoteFiltered = HighpassFilter[ViolinNote, {Quantity[5000, "Hertz"]}, 2000]
```

where 5000 Hz is the frequency above which the amplitude is below 0 dB, and observe that the sound is still audible.

Comment: `My question is about the meaning of 0 dB: does it mean that everything below 0 dB is not audible`  Yes.  this is from the internet `The intensity of energy that these sound waves produce is measured in units called decibels (dB). The lowest hearing decibel level is 0 dB, which indicates nearly total silence and is the softest sound that the human ear can hear. Generally speaking, the louder the sound, the higher the decibel number.`

Comment: But clearly here 0 db does not define the aubible sound. You may verify this by applying HighpassFilter[ViolinNote, {Quantity[5000, "Hertz"]}, 2000] and listening the resulting sound: it is audible.

Comment: https://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/dB.htm

Comment: @Syed : what is P1 used in Mathematica?

Comment: Goto standard reference level link on the page please.

Comment: @Syed : You referred me to the definition of dB. This definition depends on the reference value $P_{1}$, which defines in particular what is 0 dB. Typically, people use some value such that 0 dB is the hearing threshold. Clearly, this is not the case of Mathematica (see updates of my question). But what it is then?

Comment: from the good link Syed gave, it says `0 dB does not mean no sound, it means a sound level where the sound pressure is equal to that of the reference level. This is a small pressure, but not zero`

Comment: @Nasser : please see my comment above.

Comment: @Nasser : and the update of my question.

Comment: `p1 = Periodogram[ViolinNote, PlotStyle -> Red]` `p2 = Periodogram[AudioAmplify[ViolinNote, 1/10]]` and finally `Show[p1, p2]`. It clearly shows that 0dB on a periodogram has a different referencing and is not related to the way the term is used in the audio business.

Comment: @Syed : but what I need is the definition of $P_{1}$ used by Mathematica. Is it the same for any sound, or Mathematica defines it somehow from each sound independently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but a bit of experimentation makes things clear. First, make some simple to understand test data:

```
dc = Table[1, {x, 1, 10000}];
```

Now, do a linear scale:

```
Periodogram[dc, PlotRange -> All, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Absolute"}]
```

[image]

The result is peak at zero frequency, "power" 10000. Try default log scale:

```
Periodogram[dc, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]This yields a 40 dB peak. Sensible, given the linear result. To check, attenuate by 40 dB:

```
Periodogram[0.01 dc, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]Yields a 0 dB peak. So, the dB scale is relative to a signal whose squared samples sum to one.

```
Total[(0.01 dc)^2]
(* 1. *)
```

It has nothing to do with sound pressure. `Mathematica` cannot guess the pressure scale of your sound samples: they are numbers in a computer, not calibrated to pressure.